# How to get URL of a delete method off resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to use the url to delete a resource inside a helper I made which takes the url parameter into the href of html.

```
resources :potatoes
```

How to do this, but have it return the URL instead of a link?

Why does

```
potato_path(object, method: :delete)
potato_url(object, method: :delete)
```

Pass the method as a query string?

As an added question, how is url_for() used? It only has one argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is the right place to pass the `{method: :delete}` params. That would go in your helper, like `link_to`.

```
link_to('Yum', potato_url(obj), data: { method: :delete })
```

If you inspect the output of that you'll see something like:

```
<a data-method="delete" href="/potatos/1" rel="nofollow">Yum</a>
```

Similarly if you're using a `form_for` or `form_tag`. That's where you specify the http method, not the named path or url.

Comment: Oh god, the link itself will always be the same, since it's REST and all... I feel so stupid. I've tried grabbing "just the url" for this since ever. Now I looked at the output of your html and was like "god, I'm stupid"

Comment: I'd have to alter the helpers I've made in order to support links such as these where only the method is different. Thanks!

Comment: in link_to helper for data you need use this notation `link_to('Yum', potato_url(obj), data: { method: :delete })`